# Loop in output files?

Tags: r, for-loop, write.table

I have a function that return the results in form of output files. The user write the desire name, as: `test.dat` and  the function return the results in a file with this name in the local directory.

I want these files be numbered in increased order after run the `for` loop, by instance:

> 1.dat
>
> 2.dat
>
> ...
>
> 10000.dat

Basically, the idea is to put c("1.dat","2.dat",...,"10000.dat") in the vector output.

Comment: What is the output of `myfunction`

Comment: i delete this part, don't matter very much. Basically, the idea is to put c("1.dat","2.dat",...,"10000.dat") in the vector output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a `vector` output and we are applying on a `for` loop, either initialize a `NULL` vector and concatenate the output from the function

```
v1 <- c()
for(i in 1:1e5) v1 <- c(v1, myfunction(arg1, arg2))
v1 <- paste0(v1, ".dat")
```

Or initialize 'v1' with the full length and assign based on the index

```
v1 <- character(1e5)
for(i in 1:1e5) v1[i] <- myfunction(arg1, arg2)
v1 <- paste0(v1, ".dat")
```

Comment: I need the name ".dat" on the last of the word. This way only return one number in character form.

Comment: @VictorBarreto your example is not clear to me.  Do you need to `paste0(myfunction(arg1, arg2), ".dat")`